# Is there anything beyond NVRAM and SMC?

Tags: install

I am working on completely resetting my macbook air. So far I did a 7x disk erase and reinstalled OS X. In addition I cleared the NVRAM and the SMC. Is there any other possible system settings I can reset besides cleaning the disk, reinstalling OS X, clearing the NVRAM, and clearing the SMC?

Comment: When you reset NVRAM did you just use the keyboard combo or did you boot into single-user mode and nvram -c ?

Comment: I did the keyboard combo @da4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's about as much as needs to be done (and indeed can be done) other than removing and destroying your old drive for security purposes.

Having said that, without specialist forensic equipment the chances of recovering data from a drive that's had a single zero-fill erase is essentially zero, and is pretty much beyond the scope of consumer-level data recovery software. The excruciatingly-long 7 and 35-pass erase routines are overkill for for most people not featuring highly on the NSA's watch list. If platters were removed from the drive and read directly by specialist equipment then limited recovery *is* possible, but you'd have to be a *really* interesting person for anyone to go to such lengths.

Comment: it should be noted you can't take platters off of an SSD, its a different forensic process